# Mysql Query doubt

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables namely test1, test2, test3

```
test1 data
===========
id test_id q_id 
1    25      2
2    27      2

test2 data
===========
id test_id q_id 
1    25      2
2    34      2

test3 data
===========
id test_id q_id 
1    34      2
```

how get `test_id` value with `q_id = 2` from these three tables without repeating data ?

that is 25, 27, 34

Comment: Why do you have 3 tables with the same columns? Would this not be better off as a single `test` table with an extra column to differentiate between the 3 test runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really can't get rid of two of the three structural identical tables take a look at the [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) operator. The default behaviour is UNION *DISTINCT* which removes duplicates from the results.

```
  SELECT test_id FROM test1 WHERE q_id=2
UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT test_id FROM test2 WHERE q_id=2
UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT test_id FROM test3 WHERE q_id=2
```

Comment: this from the mysql manual (and indeed, it's the behavior prescribed by the SQL standard):

The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal.

Comment: Yes, it's the default behaviour (as already mentioned in the answer) and it also does no harm to write it explicitly into the query (for clarity).

Answer (score 1):

@just somebody - Your query is doing 3 select * which might be intensive, it is best to limit all three to avoid an unnecessary number of rows:

```
    SELECT test_id, 'test1' AS tableName FROM test1 WHERE q_id = 2
    UNION
    SELECT test_id, 'test2' AS tableName FROM test2 WHERE q_id = 2
    UNION
    SELECT test_id, 'test3' AS tableName FROM test3 WHERE q_id = 2
```

**The above query was modified to reflect which table each q_id came from.**

Comment: What's the reason for wrapping the thing in a sub-query?

Comment: isn't the database smart enough to see that it's only test_id that's needed?  i thought mysql has grown up a bit since the 3.22 days... sigh.

Comment: @VolkerK - good point, I had simply pasted and modified @just somebody's code to show the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT test_id
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM test1 UNION
    SELECT * FROM test2 UNION
    SELECT * FROM test3
) tests
WHERE q_id = 2
```

Comment: This query would cause an unnecessary amount of overhead if you are dealing with larger tables.  See solution below.